# How to get a field value of the item in ItemDeleted event handler?

Tags: event-handlers, event-receivers

I need to get the value of ListItem field in `ItemDeleted` event handler. Only value of one numeric field. But `properties.ListItem == null`. And `AfterProperties`, `BeforeProperties` also do not work.
Is there way to do this? Or pass parameter from a `ItemDeleting` to `ItemDeleted` to ****?

Answer (score 5):

For a list Deleted event we cannot get any values. Is it possible to change your code in Item Deleting Event?

For more information on List Item Events, please go through the below urls

http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2010/06/beforepropertiesafterproperties-in-event-receivers-i-always-forget-this/

http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use the event ItemDeleting.